# connection to R-30ib

Tags: ros, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I haven't been able to get through to Fanuc about this concern I have and I am wondering how a machine running ROS is typically connected to an industrial robot controller? I have an R-30ib with me and there are connections to a RS-323C port and a PCMCIA connection port as well. I'm not sure which adapter I should buy to initiate communication between my laptop and the controller. Initially I was looking for an ethernet connection but I couldn't find one on the panel, if anyone has ever had experience with using ROS on industrial robot arms could give me some advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Devin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217830/connection-to-r-30ib/) by [TheDude35](https://answers.ros.org/users/23839/thedude35/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

General comment: the [ROS-Industrial](http://ros-i.org) 'branch' of ROS is where we focus on using ROS with industrial robots. You might want to get in touch with us on the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev).

> Initially I was looking for an ethernet connection but I couldn't find one on the panel [..]

The [fanuc_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc_driver?distro=hydro) page lists the requirements on both the software and the hardware of your controller: you must have ethernet support, as well as options R632 (KAREL) and R648 (User Socket Messaging). Afaik, all R-30iB controllers come with ethernet networking installed, I'm not sure where the port(s) is (are) located inside the controller itself though.

As for the other options: please make sure you have them (they are not installed by default), otherwise the `fanuc_driver` package will not be compatible.

---

Edit: according to the *R-30iB Controller Maintenance Manual* (B-83195EN/03), Section 4.10.2.1 (Connection to Ethernet), the port is labelled CD38{A,B,C}. Pages 223 and 224 should show you where it is located.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0